# Cleaning up my controllers, can I have Merb style action defs today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rail 2.3.2 can I have merb style action definitions:

Eg: instead of

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Can I have:

```
def show(id)
  @user = User.find(id) 
end
```

What kind of crazy monkey patching do I need to do to get this working, note I only need this working for MRI so ParseTree is an option.

Note: there is a [Rails 3 port](http://github.com/adelcambre/rails-action-args/tree/master) of this functionality now.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I was wrong:** [Method#parameters](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/vframe.rb/ruby/ruby-core/19759?19595-21708+split-mode-vertical) has been added to Ruby 1.9.2.

---

**Original:**

No, this is not possible in Rails.

There is almost zero chance of this making it into Rails 3.0. [merb-action-args](http://github.com/wycats/merb/tree/master/merb-action-args) used [ParseTree](http://parsetree.rubyforge.org/) which [doesn't and will not work on Ruby 1.9](http://blog.zenspider.com/2009/04/parsetree-eol.html), therefore making it unlikely that it will be included in Rails.

Comment: Actually it was just ported to Rails 3.0 ... http://github.com/adelcambre/rails-action-args/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

You could change all params in to instance var's (eg. @id) in a before_filter...

Answer (score -1):

I am running Rails 2.3.3 and User.find(id) works just fine.

Comment: notice the sig on def show(id), in rails actions have no params, they all get accessed via params see: http://journal.uggedal.com/looking-at-merb-again look how actions are defined

Comment: Opps.  So you want to convert the params hash into local variables available to the controller?  Or pass the params hash to the method according to the variables defined.  These seems like a reasonably easy thing to achieve.